# Windows service C# - Error 1064 on DB connection, Create XML from DB

Tags: c#, sql, xml, windows-services

I have a problem with Running the Windows Service. Service is connecting DB and through DataAdapter it creates local XML file. Then it transfer the file to the FTP server. 
Get error 1064 when trying to start the service.

I checked and the error occurs when trying to create XML file from DB. I guese it's DB connection but don't know how to fix it.

When i run this code as Console app it works pretty well, no errors occures, but when i run it as windows service it is occuring :/ Maybe it is something with Connection string? or with Creating XML file throught DataAdapter? What's the difference here between Console App and windows service Connection to DB?

To check it, I commented out the part with connection to DB (CreateXML() method) and it works too, so FTP connection is not an issue.

I marked with comment the line of code which throw an error, it's located in the CreateXML() Method.

You have full code here

EDIT (solution):
If you have the same problem change Service to use your win account. Works without errors now.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;

namespace XMLShopService
{
    public partial class XMLShopService : ServiceBase
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        //TIME MULTIPLIERS 
        private static int seconds = 1000;          //miliseconds to SECONDS multiplier -- DON'T TOUCH --
        private static int minutes = 60000;         //miliseconds to MINUTES multiplier -- DON'T TOUCH --
        private static int hours = 3600000;         //miliseconds to HOURS multiplier -- DON'T TOUCH --

        //TIME INTERVAL SETTINGS
        private int timeInterval = 3;              //SET HERE - time interval in (SECONDS or MINUTES or HOURS), then pick timeMultiplier below
        private int timeMultiplier = minutes;       //SET HERE - time format you would like to use in timer as interval (SECONDS or MINUTES or HOURS) pick one from above and implement after "="

        public XMLShopService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();

            WriteToFile("START : " + DateTime.Now);

            CreateXML();
            FtpFileUpload();

            //TIMER
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            timer.Interval = timeInterval * timeMultiplier;             // -- DON'T TOUCH -- Represent time interval in MILISECONDS  
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
           WriteToFile("STOP : " + DateTime.Now);
        }




        //FUNCTIONS USED
        private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteToFile("ReStart script at : " + DateTime.Now);

            CreateXML();
            FtpFileUpload();

            WriteToFile("Script finished at : " + DateTime.Now);

        }





        private void CreateXML()
        {
            //XML file settings
            string fileName = "file.xml";                                           //SET HERE - XML local file name
            string localFilePath = @"path" + fileName;                //SET HERE - XML local file path (full) 
            double priceMultiplier = 3;                                             //SET HERE - price multiplier

            //SQL Query - products codes & prices * multiplier
            string queryString = "SELECT ItemCode, Price * " + priceMultiplier + " FROM database WHERE PriceList = 1 AND Price > 0";

            //SQL connection string
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = @"Server=server;" +            //SET HERE - SQL Server
                                     "Initial Catalog=database;" +           //SET HERE - Server database
                                     "Integrated Security=true";

            //Creating XML file in the specific location, overwriting old file
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn) { CommandType = CommandType.Text })
                {
                    WriteToFile("SQL 1: " + DateTime.Now);

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlComm);
                    WriteToFile("SQL 2: " + DateTime.Now);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);                              //!!!---THIS IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS---!!!
                    WriteToFile("SQL 3: " + DateTime.Now);

                    ds.Tables[0].WriteXml(localFilePath);     
                    WriteToFile("SQL 4: " + DateTime.Now);
                }
                WriteToFile("DB connection ok: " + DateTime.Now);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                WriteToFile("ERROR - create file: " + DateTime.Now);
                throw;
            }

        }

        private void FtpFileUpload()
        {
            string ftpUsername = "userName";                                                //SET HERE - FTP username
            string ftpPassword = "pass";                                                           //SET HERE - FTP Password

            string ftpFolderPath = @"ftpServerPath/test/";          //SET HERE - FTP folder dir   -- TODO: TEST FOLDER PATH TO CHANGE --
            string fileName = "file.xml";                                                               //SET HERE - XML local file name
            string localFilePath = @"path" + fileName;                                    //SET HERE - XML local file dir (full)


            //DELETE old file
            try
            {
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpFolderPath + fileName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);

                using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    WriteToFile(response.StatusDescription + " " + DateTime.Now);
                }
            }

            //Throw on errors
            catch (Exception)
            {
                WriteToFile("ERROR - delete old file: " + DateTime.Now);
                throw;
            }


            //UPLOAD UpToDate file
            try
            {
                //Set request
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpFolderPath + fileName);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.KeepAlive = true;

                //Load file
                FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];

                stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                stream.Close();

                //Upload file
                Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                reqStream.Close();

                using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    WriteToFile(response.StatusDescription + " " + DateTime.Now);
                }
                request = null;
            }

            //Throw on errors
            catch (Exception)
            {
                WriteToFile("ERROR - upload UpToDate file: " + DateTime.Now);
                throw;
            }
        }


        //SCRIPT LOGS
        public void WriteToFile(string Message)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs";
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Logs\\ServiceLog.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                // Create a file to write to.   
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filepath))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess it's related to your connection string. It uses integrated security which means it uses the identity of whoever is running it. Usually a service is run as a system account, which is different from when you run it in a console. I suggest you try setting the service to run as your account as a starting point. You'll probably want to specify a full path to where you want the file to be written, because services have strange 'current' directories, so a full path is a better idea.

Comment: Thanks. According to your suggestions I changed the service to run with my Account. Works as i wanted now ;)